# jQuery UI - Resize - Only one handle with aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize

I'm using jQuery UI to make an image resizable like this

```
.resizable({
      handles: 's,e,se'
});
```

And i would like the se handle to keep aspect ratio, not the other one.

I've tried like this:

```
   .resizable({
          handles: 's,e'
    }).resizable({
          handles: 'se',
          aspectRatio:true
    });
```

But it's not working... and Idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Solved: Keeps aspect ratio when resizing with the corners, but not with the sides

[ html ]

```
<div class="ResizableDiv"></div>
```

[ javascript ]

```
jDiv = $('.ResizableDiv');

jDiv.resizable({                    
    handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se",
    start: function( event, ui ) {                          
        if ($(event.originalEvent.target).attr('class').match(/\b(ui-resizable-se|ui-resizable-sw|ui-resizable-ne|ui-resizable-nw)\b/)){
            // Keep aspect ratio when resizing using the corners
            jDiv.resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", true ).data('uiResizable')._aspectRatio = true;
        }       
    },  
    stop: function( event, ui ) {   
        // remove aspect ratio resize
        jDiv.resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", false ).data('uiResizable')._aspectRatio = false;      
    }
});
```

Comment: This gives me error... saying can not use option method while resizing...

Comment: it's weird that `$("selector").resizable( "option", "aspectRatio", true )` alone won't work, as the answer suggested you have to add this part `.data('uiResizable')._aspectRatio = true` after that everything work fine

Answer (score 2):

I answer to myself:

```
start: function(e,ui) {
  if (jQuery(e.originalTarget).hasClass("ui-resizable-se")) {
     // Keep aspect ratio function
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the keep aspect ratio function you are using? something you wrote, or a jquery ui function?

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery UI resizable for single handle aspect ratio use this function
$("#Resize_aspect").resizable({ aspectRatio:true });